# Can't initialize Redis as a systemd service (supervised systemd) on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2

Tags: systemd, redis, ubuntu-20.04, systemd-service

On Ubuntu Server 20.04, Redis (5.0.7) doesn't start after setting `supervised systemd` on `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, but no error is printed when running it manually with `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Also, when running manually, its possible to find it listening on port 6379 with `netstat -tulpn`.

**To reproduce**

As root:

- Update packages and install Redis with `apt update && apt install redis-server`
- On `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, change the line with `supervised no` to `supervised systemd`
- Try to restart Redis with `service redis-server restart` or `systemctl restart redis`

The output of the above command is:

```
Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And the output of `systemctl status redis-server.service` is:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-03 12:15:56 -03; 28s ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 3851 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 03 12:15:56 mywebsite.com systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 03 12:15:56 mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
Feb 03 12:15:56 mywebsite.com systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 03 12:15:56 mywebsite.com systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 03 12:15:56 mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

No log is printed on `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log` when trying to restart Redis service, but the text below is printed when running it manually:

````
4231:C 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.053 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
4231:C 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.053 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=4231, just started
4231:C 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.053 # Configuration loaded
4232:M 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.063 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 5.0.7 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 4232
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

4232:M 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.065 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
4232:M 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.065 # Server initialized
4232:M 03 Feb 2021 12:27:52.066 * Ready to accept connections
````

**Software versions:**

Redis server v=5.0.7 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=636cde3b5c7a3923

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - 64 bit

systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4)

Comment: Original issue: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8443

Comment: Yes, the container is an Ubuntu 20.04 server. I install Redis using `apt install redis-server`

Comment: Informed systemd version on question: 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty strange, but Ubuntu's installation of redis-server *does not* use redis's ability to communicate with systemd. On this platform you should leave redis.conf set as it shipped: `supervised no`.

---

If you *really* want to enable this for some reason, you will have to customize the systemd unit, for example:

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl edit redis-server.service
```

In nano, you should add only this:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
```

Then tell systemd to load the changes.

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you need to edit redis.conf:

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

And make these changes:

```
daemonize no
supervised systemd
```

Now you can restart redis-server:

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl start redis-server
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl status redis-server
* redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service.d
             `-override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-02-03 11:55:09 EST; 1min 8s ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
   Main PID: 1768 (redis-server)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 2318)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
             `-1768 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Feb 03 11:55:09 vmtest-ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Feb 03 11:55:09 vmtest-ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

Comment: Even that your answer doesn't solve my issue, from my little experience, it seems the right one.

Comment: In my case, Redis doesn't work in both cases. Even after returning everything to the initial state, it isn't starting.

Comment: @PauloCoghi Check `journalctl -b -u redis-server` for possible clues.

Comment: systemd is fighting with the Redis service:

Comment: `redis-server.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/dev: Invalid argument`

Comment: `redis-server.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/redis-server: Invalid argument`

Comment: What is strange is that the issue persist even after removing Redis package completely with `apt-get purge redis-server*`, and reinstalling it again.

Comment: Something more significant is wrong with your system. Most likely some incompatibility with OpenVZ (which many of us have had bad experiences with and won't recommend).

Comment: I believe the problem is on my side, but only on this specific container. Anyway, I appreciate all the information!

Comment: I discovered the issue. For an unknown reason, the owner or permissions on `/var/lib/redis` and/or `/var/log/redis` and/or `/var/run/redis` were not ok. I changed to redis:redis and now, everything is fine.

Comment: Similar experience here - I believe a previous install of redis has interfered in some way with its ability to run via systemd on one of my systems - have tried everything suggested here and elsewhere to no avail.   However, I have no problems running via systemd on multiple other systems where there was no previous redis install.   After many hours, had to throw in the towel on the problematic system and run via Docker.    The lack of verbose logging here was really the killer - can't do much with `Failed to start Advanced key-value store.` [mutter, grumble...]

Answer (score -1):

use - `sudo systemctl start redis.service` for the first time