# ubuntu 22.04 redis.service stops working after adding tls

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, redis

A fresh install of redis on ubuntu 22.04: I changed `supervised no` to `supervised systemd`. When running `systemctl start redis.service`, everything works as expected.

I now change the redis.conf file to use TLS: I set `port 0` and `tls-port 6379`, and I also added the ssl-files to it.

When now restarting the service with `systemctl restart redis.service` I get an error but nothing really is logged, it just fails.

By running `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf` directly, everything works, and when testing the TLS-connection, it also works, so I don't think there is anything wrong with my redis config-file.

I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052285/cant-initialize-redis-as-a-systemd-service-supervised-systemd-on-ubuntu-serve) here on serverfault. The difference is: before editing the redis.conf-file, everything works as expected.

What could I possibly do to get the service working again?

**Edit:**

This is the only error I get in journal:

> Mar 21 08:26:21 services-server systemd[1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052285/cant-initialize-redis-as-a-systemd-service-supervised-systemd-on-ubuntu-serve): redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

> Mar 21 08:26:21 services-server systemd[1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052285/cant-initialize-redis-as-a-systemd-service-supervised-systemd-on-ubuntu-serve): redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: What does your log show? Any error messages in the journal?

Comment: no, my journal output gives the message that it couldn't be restarted, but no clear error message

Comment: I've edited my question with the error I seem to get in journal